# Cannot deploy node app on Azure Website

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

An app I used to deploy continuously "suddenly" does not deploy anymore.
It seems KuduSync is the culprit, because /repository is up-to-date with the repo, but not /wwwroot.

I've tried to modify files obviously, change the package.json version, change the node version.

here is the complete deployment log, even with some files changed, there is no trace of them.

```
2016-03-01T10:17:53  Updating submodules.
2016-03-01T10:17:54  Preparing deployment for commit id '005869b2f2'.
2016-03-01T10:17:55  Generating deployment script.
2016-03-01T10:17:55    Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --node -- sitePath "D:\home\site\repository"').
2016-03-01T10:17:55  Running deployment command...
2016-03-01T10:17:55    Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
2016-03-01T10:17:55    Handling node.js deployment.
2016-03-01T10:17:59    KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
2016-03-01T10:17:59    The package.json file does not specify node.js engine version constraints.
2016-03-01T10:17:59    The node.js application will run with the default node.js version 5.7.0.
2016-03-01T10:17:59    Selected npm version 3.6.0
2016-03-01T10:18:37    Finished successfully.
2016-03-01T10:18:38  Running post deployment command(s)...
2016-03-01T10:18:38  Deployment successful.
```

Have anyone encountered this before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... disconnect and reconnect the continuous deployment seemed to fix it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯